# PHP "Enter code to win" Solution reading a simple .txt file

Tags: php

I want to create a competition. I'm not good with php but can see this could be the only way to do it. I would like to create a script using a simple one field form where the customer enters a code and when they click submit it will look at a text file and any matching results will be returned with a congratulations page and any not matching will return a sorry you haven't won this time page. Would this be fairly simple to do?

I could expand on this and have the whole list of 13,000 codes in a sql database and once a code is entered it exhausts that code so if entered again it will return a sorry, this code has already been entered/used?

Would there be a simple way of emailing an address saying something has been submitted?

Edit:

Using an answer below I have got this far:

```
    <?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "*****";
$password = "*****";
$code = $_POST[ 'code' ];

  if ( $client_code ) {

    $db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=*****", $username, $password);

    $statement = $db -> prepare( 'SELECT 1 FROM codes WHERE code = ?' );
    $statement -> bindParam( 1, $code );
    $statement -> execute();

    $result = $statement -> fetchAll();

    if ( $result ) {
      header( 'Location: success.php' ); // Redirects to success page
      die();
    }
      header( 'Location: fail.php' ); // Redirects to fail page
      die();
    }

   else {
    header( 'Location: no_code.php' ); // Redirects to no code entered page
    die();
  }

?>
```

But it keeps flagging up with this error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in mysite/mypahe.php on line 11

Can anyone help?

Comment: instead of a textfile you should do a database. Its easier. You can compare in a database values. Then just work with an if else statement. If the statement is true (so if there is a row with that code in it) you link to win price, else to a lose price. Its fairly easy. Make a count mark and add, if a code is enter from 0 to 1 (so i binary field) if the statement is 1.. And php has its own email function, so yes, that is possible.

Comment: How do you generate those codes ??? do they have specific algorithm or they are random

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question? It seems perfectly valid to me.

Comment: emailing an address: mail() http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: They will be generated prior to print and populated then the winners will be generated at random and slotted into the database

Comment: Look at the code colorer. That is one of the most important reasons why a code colorer helps a lot. You cannot start a string with `'` and end it with `"`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a db table named `codes` something like this:

```
+------------+--------+
| promo_code | status |
+------------+--------+
| s72jasdih  |      0 |
| asd893kla  |      0 |
| Sasd93ja3  |      0 |
+------------+--------+
```

Now in index page create a simple form:

```
<form action="actions.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="client_code" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Once you enter the code and press submit the user will be redirected to `actions.php` page with this content:

```
<?php

  $client_code = $_POST[ 'client_code' ];

  if ( $client_code ) {

    $db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=' . $db_host . ';dbname=' . $db_name, $db_user_name, $db_password );

    $statement = $db -> prepare( 'SELECT 1 FROM codes WHERE promo_code = ?' );
    $statement -> bindParam( 1, $clients_code );
    $statement -> execute();

    $result = $statement -> fetchAll();

    if ( $result ) {
      header( 'Location: success.php' ); // Redirects to success page
      die();
    }
      header( 'Location: fail.php' ); // Redirects to fail page
      die();
    }

  } else {
    header( 'Location: no_code.php' ); // Redirects to no code entered page
    die();
  }

?>
```

This is a fast example on what you have to do. To get it fully working, go through the PHP manuals and get to work ;)

Comment: Thank you, it's appreciated. I'll give this a bash

Comment: Hi, i edited my post above. I keep getting an error

Comment: Your problem is where exactly the error says it is: `$db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=*****", $username, $password);` You are opening with single quotes `'` but closing with double `"`

Comment: Thanks, I have it working somewhat now, the only issue I have is that it returns the success page for both 1's and 0's in the db and if it isn't in the db then it returns the fail page

Comment: Well, as I said, it was an example. If you want to use the `status` as `shown` feature, then make another query before success, that updates the field to 1. And add another parameter that check only, if `status = 0`.

Comment: + update your question w/ your current code please.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple script. Here is [short tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp).

Having codes in a database will be better. In order to select rows and insert data into database tables [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions can be used.

For emailing results, one can use [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mail.php) function, or [PHPMailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) class (supports multiple mail protocols)